# terraform and csv for data source

Tags: terraform

So I am trying to use Terraform to provision multiple VM's in vSphere. I have a CSV that contains the information for provisioning the guests. When I hard code the data sources the VM's are provisioned, but when I try to use the csv to populate those same sources Terraform plan tells me that the datacenter is not defined. I have tried both CSVDECODE and the interpolation methods, neither has worked.

example csvdecode:

```
locals {
  virtualmachines = csvdecode(file("${path.module}/virtualmachines.csv"))
}

data "vsphere_datacenter" "dc" {
  count = length(local.virtualmachines)
  name =  local.virtualmachines[count.index].dcname
}
```

example interpolation:

```
locals {
  virtualmachines = csvdecode(file("${path.module}/server_list.csv"))
}

    # Creating terraform resources from a CSV file using interpolation

    data "null_data_source" "csv_file" {
      inputs = {
        file_data = "${chomp(file("${path.module}/virtualmachines.csv"))}"
               }
    }

resource "null_resource" "csv_interpolation_method" {
  count = "${length(slice(split("\n", lookup(data.null_data_source.csv_file.outputs, "file_data")), 1, length(split("\n", lookup(data.null_data_source.csv_file.outputs, "file_data")))))}"

  triggers = {
    01 = "${element(split(",", element(slice(split("\n", lookup(data.null_data_source.csv_file.outputs, "file_data")), 1, length(split("\n", lookup(data.null_data_source.csv_file.outputs, "file_data")))), count.index)), 0)}"
    02 = "${element(split(",", element(slice(split("\n", lookup(data.null_data_source.csv_file.outputs, "file_data")), 1, length(split("\n", lookup(data.null_data_source.csv_file.outputs, "file_data")))), count.index)), 1)}"
    03 = "${element(split(",", element(slice(split("\n", lookup(data.null_data_source.csv_file.outputs, "file_data")), 1, length(split("\n", lookup(data.null_data_source.csv_file.outputs, "file_data")))), count.index)), 2)}"
    04 = "${element(split(",", element(slice(split("\n", lookup(data.null_data_source.csv_file.outputs, "file_data")), 1, length(split("\n", lookup(data.null_data_source.csv_file.outputs, "file_data")))), count.index)), 3)}"
    05 = "${element(split(",", element(slice(split("\n", lookup(data.null_data_source.csv_file.outputs, "file_data")), 1, length(split("\n", lookup(data.null_data_source.csv_file.outputs, "file_data")))), count.index)), 4)}"
    06 = "${element(split(",", element(slice(split("\n", lookup(data.null_data_source.csv_file.outputs, "file_data")), 1, length(split("\n", lookup(data.null_data_source.csv_file.outputs, "file_data")))), count.index)), 5)}"
    07 = "${element(split(",", element(slice(split("\n", lookup(data.null_data_source.csv_file.outputs, "file_data")), 1, length(split("\n", lookup(data.null_data_source.csv_file.outputs, "file_data")))), count.index)), 6)}"
    08 = "${element(split(",", element(slice(split("\n", lookup(data.null_data_source.csv_file.outputs, "file_data")), 1, length(split("\n", lookup(data.null_data_source.csv_file.outputs, "file_data")))), count.index)), 7)}"
    09 = "${element(split(",", element(slice(split("\n", lookup(data.null_data_source.csv_file.outputs, "file_data")), 1, length(split("\n", lookup(data.null_data_source.csv_file.outputs, "file_data")))), count.index)), 8)}"
    10 = "${element(split(",", element(slice(split("\n", lookup(data.null_data_source.csv_file.outputs, "file_data")), 1, length(split("\n", lookup(data.null_data_source.csv_file.outputs, "file_data")))), count.index)), 9)}"
  }
}


locals {
  dcname    = null_resource.csv_interpolation_method.*.triggers.01
  storage   = null_resource.csv_interpolation_method.*.triggers.02
  pool      = null_resource.csv_interpolation_method.*.triggers.03
  vtemplate = null_resource.csv_interpolation_method.*.triggers.04
  vname     = null_resource.csv_interpolation_method.*.triggers.05
  cpu       = null_resource.csv_interpolation_method.*.triggers.06
  memory    = null_resource.csv_interpolation_method.*.triggers.07
  disk      = null_resource.csv_interpolation_method.*.triggers.08
  network   = null_resource.csv_interpolation_method.*.triggers.09
  guest_id  = null_resource.csv_interpolation_method.*.triggers.10
}

output "server_output" {
  value = "${local.dcname}"
}

data "vsphere_datacenter" "dc" {
  name = "${output.server_output}"
}

output "storage" {
  value = "${local.storage}"
}

data "vsphere_datastore" "datastore" {
  name          = "${local.storage}"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}

output "pool" {
  value = "${local.pool}"
}

data "vsphere_resource_pool" "pool" {
  name          = "${local.pool}"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}

output "network" {
  value = "${local.network}"
}

data "vsphere_network" "network" {
  name          = "${local.network}"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}

output "template" {
  value = "${local.vtemplate}"
}

data "vsphere_virtual_machine" "template" {
  name          = "${local.vtemplate}"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}


resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  count = length(local.virtualmachines)

  name             = local.virtualmachines[count.index].vname
  resource_pool_id = "${data.vsphere_resource_pool.pool.id}"
  datastore_id     = "${data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id}"

  num_cpus                   = local.virtualmachines[count.index].cpu
  memory                     = local.virtualmachines[count.index].memory
  guest_id                   = local.virtualmachines[count.index].guest_id
  wait_for_guest_net_timeout = 0

  network_interface {
    network_id = "${data.vsphere_network.network.id}"
  }

  disk {
    label = "disk0"
    size  = local.virtualmachines[count.index].disk
  }

  clone {
    template_uuid = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.id}"
```

sample csv content:

```
dcname,storage,pool,vtemplate,vname,cpu,memory,disk,network,guest_id
txpla-w01-dc,txpla-w01-vsan,txpla-w01-shared01/Resources,AHLC75-template,terraform-test1,2,1024,80,Guest VLAN 1017,centos64Guest
txpla-w02-dc,txpla-w02-vsan,txpla-w02-shared01/Resources,AHLC75-template,terraform-test2,3,2048,80,Guest VLAN 1017,centos64Guest
```

Error message from interpolation method (it never makes it down to the resource)

```
A managed resource "output" "server_output" has not been declared in the root module
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Thank you

Comment: Suggest you format your post better to help people help you. I've done the first four lines to help show you how.

Comment: The Terraform resource which creates the VMs should be included as well as the problem seems to be there. The actual error message from Terraform should also be included.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions on formatting and content. 
Steve

Answer (score 1):

In Terraform, `output` blocks declare values to be passed to the calling module (or, if you're already in the root module, to be shown in the console output after applying).

You can't refer to them from within the module that defines them, and so Terraform is interpreting `output.server_output` as a resource reference, like you had a block in your configuration like `resource "output" "server_output"`, from a hypothetical provider named "output" (which doesn't actually exist).

If you want to refer to a particular value from multiple places in the *same* module without duplicating its expression, you can use Local Values instead. You already have `local.dcname`, which is what `output "server_output"` refers to, so if you replace the `output.server_output` reference with `local.dcname` instead then it should produce the result value you were looking for.

Comment: I will try again with your suggestion on Monday. Thanks  Steve